# Is Total Reputation Calculated Differently to a Time-based Reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation

As the title suggests, I am curious to know whether the "total reputation" for an account is calculated differently from the different time-based reputations. While looking at [the Year 2021 rankings](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/year/askubuntu/2021-01-01/1222991#1222991) I noticed a slight discrepancy:

[image: Off By Twelve]

The total value is twelve points lower than the reputation for the year. Initially I figured this was due to a caching issue, so waited until after midnight UTC for the Stack Exchange stats to be updated. However, the 12-point discrepancy persists.

Thinking this might have to do with downvotes being uncounted in the yearly calculation, I went to see how many of these have been given and how many were received.

The summary view shows 10 downvotes:

[image: Whole Lot of Voting]

The detail view shows 3 downvotes:

[image: Three is not Ten]

<sup>Perhaps the summary includes posts that were flagged as spam?</sup>

It's difficult to quickly determine how many downvotes have been received, so a little bit of "hacking" reveals this:

[image: What do you call Negative One sitting alone in a room?]

This breaks down as:

- 22 points from downvotes
- 12 points from removed posts
- 3 points from posts I downvoted (though only one is in the list — oops)

Looking at these numbers, is it fair to say the following things are true:

1. if we delete an answer, we're dinged 2 points (plus any points as a result of votes)
2. yearly reputation calculations do not take into account removed posts

---

Edit:

Using the very helpful [text-based reputation link](https://askubuntu.com/reputation), the reputation for the year is shown as being 5864, which would be 5,965 - 100 (Association Bonus) - 1 (Everyone gets a Point):

```
** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2021-10-24 - 2021-10-30): 93
** rep this month (2021-10-01 - 2021-10-31): 641
** rep this quarter (2021-10-01 - 2021-12-31): 641
** rep this year (2021-01-01 - 2021-12-31): 5864
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 5965 :)
```

I guess this is just one of those situations where numbers don't match because different elements look at different criteria which is (probably) cached at different times

Comment: you don't lose points for deleting an answer (all reputation changes arising from votes on the answer are reversed, but there's no penalty for deleting), but if an answer you received reputation for editing is deleted, you lose the 2 points you got for your edit. That's what "removed" means in the list. This may well be the discount from the yearly rep, but I am not sure. BTW you may find https://askubuntu.com/reputation useful

Comment: @Zanna Oh my. /reputation is very useful indeed. Thank you for this 

Comment: @Zanna are there more pages like https://askubuntu.com/reputation ? How can we know about them?

Comment: Hmm I don't know about any other pages like that